# Razor - Passing DropDownList selected value to Controller via Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-select

I am trying to pass the dropdownlist value to my controller so I can add the values to a list of paycodes but I keep getting a "Value cannot be null." error. My paycode list has many items in it. Not sure what is null or wrong here...

INNER EXCEPTION

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
```

VIEW

```
        <!-- products input-->
        <div class="control-group col-lg-6">
            <label class="control-label">Product</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddPayCode", "Referral",
    new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "PayCodes",
        Url = Url.Action("AddPayCode", "Referral")
    }))
                {
                    @Html.ValidationSummary()

                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPayCode, new SelectList(Model.PayCodes.ToList(), "Id", "Description"), "- Select -")
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddPayCode(ReferralModel model)
{
    var test = model.SelectedPayCode;
    //TODO: Add to model.Referral.PayCodes list and return list of selected items
}
```

MODEL

```
public class ReferralModel
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public List<PayCode> PayCodes { get; set; }
    public int SelectedPayCode { get; set; }

    public Referral Referral { get; set; }
}
```

DOMAIN OBJECT

```
public class Referral
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PayCode> PayCodes { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Objective :

- User chooses a paycode from the dropdown and clicks "Add" Paycode is
- added to the referral PayCodes list
- Controller returns the list of    paycodes selected to the view (not
  yet implemented)

Comment: The exception tell you about what is null... but I can't see the parameter source anywhere in the question! You should post It!

Comment: I don't have a parameter called source, anywhere in my project. This is what has been so confusing for me.

Comment: You should post more info about the exception! When its occurs? Another thing, you already provide the route for post in the form function, so you don't need Url = Url.Action("AddPayCode", "Referral")

Comment: List<PayCode> PayCodes = new List<PayCode>(); looks missing (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the controller is missing the property of the dropdown list.

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddPayCode(ReferralModel model, ** string SelectedPayCode ** <-- missing)
{
    var test = SelectedPayCode;
    //TODO: Add to model.Referral.PayCodes list and return list of selected items
}
```